# How to enable subviews' tab gesture in the UIPickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a custom view that has tap gesture in the pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) method. When I tap the uitextview inside the reuse view, there is no response for the tap event and the testviewdidbeginediting is not called. Does the UIpicker block the tap events for its' subviews? Do I need to overwrite some response chain method in order to allow the reuse view to get the tap event? [image] [image]

Comment: Did you try checking a view hierarchy in xCode at a runtime?

Comment: Would help if you included some code

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks for your help